# Deserializing Objects in Java

Tags: java, serialization

Say I have a large file with many objects already serialized (this is the easy part). I need to be able to have random access to the objects in the file when I go to deserialize. The only way I can think to do this would be to somehow store the file pointer to each object.

Basically I will end up with a large file of serialized objects and don't want to deserialize the entire file when I go to retrieve just one object.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one?

Comment: How about using some kind of object DB? Something like [Neodatis](http://neodatis.wikidot.com/) (there are many other, see this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems))

Comment: What if you serialize the object into a directory structure with a look-up file at the top level of the directory. Every time you need an object you parse the look-up file, then grab the file you need for the particular object. Just a thought.

Comment: I am trying to store a skiplist on file... so I need to serialize and deserialze Skip Nodes. Is there some way that using the skiplist allows me to access the nodes I need? I feel like I would still need a file pointer to get the correct object

Comment: What kind of object do you wanna store? Are all objects of the same type? Are the objects of variable size (Collections?)?

Comment: The objects are of generic type, they are collections yes

Comment: How often does the data change?  Can you just serialize the entire skip list and then read it back into memory when you need it?  How many objects and how big are they once serialized on to the disk?  The problem here is that as your requirements get more complicated, you're basically writing a database from scratch.  Easier to just use a DB from the start.

Comment: Oh you're definitely right about it being easier to just use an in memory skip list, but for this assignment we cannot unfortunately. The data changes pretty consistently as each command is usually an insert or delete. I thought about reading in and writing the entire skip list each time but I feel like there should be a better way to do it if you just want to change one object.

Comment: *"The data changes pretty consistently as each command is usually an insert or delete. "* ... I don't see how.  There is no Platform API for editing serialized streams.  The only operations that are intended for a serialized stream of objects are writing and reading (byte editing a stream is not usual or intended).  To me, it sounds like you want your serialized objects in either an LDAP directory, an RDBMS, or an OODB.  I'm quite sure that I don't understand the goals of your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Serialization is called serialization for a reason. It is serial. Random access into a stream of objects will not work, for several reasons including the stream header, object handles, ...

Comment: Why wouldn't storing a file pointer to where the object begins work? I think that's what we're supposed to do... use a handle to store the start position and the length and then deserialize. Would this work?

Comment: @LoganM Because previously serialized objects aren't re-serialized. If an object contains a member that has already been serialized in the stream, it isn't re-serialized. So correct deserialization of that object depends on reading the entire stream to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Straight serialization will never be the solution you want.
The `serial` portion of the name means that the objects are written linearly to the `ObjectOutputStream`.

The serialization format is well known,
here is a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) to the java 6 serialization format.

You have several options:

1. Unserialize the entire file and go from there.
2. Write code to read the serialized file and generate an index.
   Maybe even store the index in a file for future use.
3. Abandon serialization to a file and store the objects in a database.

Comment: An index will not work. The entire stream has to be read up to the point where the required object is.